# How to protect express.js api from post requests, that is not coming from my mobile app?

Tags: node.js, security, express

I have built a simple Express.js Api for my Mobile Application.

I know it is quite easy to restrict access to some IP addresses, but what to do if I want to allow my API be accessed by Mobile App as well?

Comment: Create an authentication/login system to track usage by account, set up terms of service and suspend or rate limit any accounts that are abusing your service.  That's how Google does it.  You can't outright restrict access from only certain types of devices.

Comment: Any headers can be spoofed, including the originating IP address in extreme cases, so as @jfriend00 has correctly recommended, you just need an authentication system. There are plenty out-of-the-box solutions already available for express, you just need to use your google-fu to find them.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, can you name one?

Comment: passport is probably the most widely used system for node.js auth and it contains support for leveraging lots of existing auth systems (facebook, google, etc...).

Comment: You might also want to take a look at client certificates. More info here: http://intown.biz/2016/11/22/node-client-auth/